# Python leaderboards from highest to lowest

Tags: python

I need to order the 'score' from highest to lowest alongside the 'name' but it wont let me, it prints the 'score' and 'name' in a list but not in order

(There in a name for the 'winner' and a int for 'points')

```
import csv
score=points
username=winner
with open ("write.csv", "a", newline='') as file:  
    fields=['score', 'name']                      
    writer=csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writerow({'score' : score, 'name' : username})

with open ("write.csv", "r") as file:
    sortlist=[]
    reader=csv.reader(file)
    for i in reader:
        sortlist.append(i)
for i in range(len(sortlist)):   #it does not order correctly
    if i != 0:
        time.sleep(0.1)

print()
print("The End")
time.sleep(1)
print()
print("LeaderBoards")
print()
time.sleep(1)
for i in range(len(sortlist)1):
    print(sortlist[i])
```

I expect the output to be from highest to lowest alongside the name i.e

```
['53', 'James']
['26', 'Bob']
['65', 'John']

To-

['65', 'John']
['53', 'James']
['26', 'Bob']

All i need is a line or a couple for it to print highest to lowest alongside the 'username'
```

Comment: Include a short example for "write.csv".. for example 5 lines. Include the column name and number rows. (End of Review).

Comment: i dont know what you mean???

Comment: it is an excel file with no column name and number row, if it needs it could you help me do that with your code please

Comment: Row 1 - contester "Ben" - score 2 at biathlon - score 7 at triathlon. Just think about it... if you don't have "write.csv"... what am I testing against? So if I want to test your above script... then "give" me a write.csv example to run against. You expect a certain output but its uncertain the csv file is build like what you expect... so help me..and other to help you ;-)

Comment: its fine if its only in python, it does not have to edit the excel file

Comment: The line `with open ("write.csv", "a", newline='') as file:` is using the write.csv file... right? Just proved a snippet version of it to run against. Providing it in python is fine too.. whatever rocks your boot.. but without "input" no testing. And provide the python method how the list is treated aswell...

Comment: Its like this:     Name,Email,Phone Number,Address:

    Bob Smith,bob@example.com,123-456-7890,123 Fake Street;

    Mike Jones,mike@example.com,098-765-4321,321 Fake Avenu. And that boring stuff... five times.

Comment: Tbh I don’t know what u mean, all I need is for the ‘score to be ordered with the name alongside

Comment: How am I able to test your script without data... just provide DATA (name1, score 1, score 2; name2, score1, score 2 or whatever you have in for example five lines in that write.csv file. How difficult can it be?

Comment: I.e [‘65’, ‘Bob’] [‘24’, ‘Steve’] [‘54’, ‘James’] to [24’, ‘Steve’] [‘54’, ‘James’] [‘65’, ‘Bob’]

Comment: Yes! Put something like that from your comment in your question.

Comment: No basically you have misunderstood the python code at the end add to the file so for example at the end it adds a new row with a name and a number. There is nothing in the write.csv

Comment: Your data.. just put it in your question to be used. I don't give a hoot... where it comes from..its not provided in the question. So provide a DATA set!! (Could have helped you out here with a "dataset" but instead end up repeatedly pointing at your missing dataset. End of Review).

Comment: So can you help or not?

Comment: You could have came up with ur own dataset and seen if it had been put in order???

Comment: When new people join their question get always reviewed for validity, uniqueness and completeness. If I would fix your code with my own imaginary dataset I can spend hours on it and still not fixing it accordingly your criteria by using the wrong type of dataset, order or incorrect amount of datapoints, etc. As expert you know how it should look at detail-level which means the question is labeled "too broad" (i.e. unclear what you mean) by us. Most people just "click" label it and the question gets on-hold or deleted. I saw the question validity as good, non-pandas, example and helped you ;-)

Comment: Why would you assume the data to be ordered? You never sort it.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean???

Comment: between `with open ("write.csv", "r") as file:` and `for i in range(len(sortlist)):` is no sorting done. The sorting I've presented in my answer can be put there but  my suggestion is to run and play my code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i needed was
    sortlist.sort(reverse = True)

Answer (score 0):

with pandas is more easy , just like this ....(before make you sure have pandas installed ....  pip install pandas)

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('write.csv',delimiter=',')
#With pandas
print(df.sort(['score'], ascending=[0]))

#To list
list = df.values.tolist()
print(list)
```

Comment: 'install' is an invalid syntax

Comment: pip install pandas or pip3 install pandas

Comment: All i want is a line or a couple to add to my original code so it orders from highest to lowest alongside the 'username' from my original code

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want to work with two lists for comparison instead of dicts.

In the answer I've added constructive comments explaining where does what. I did not include the duplicate score cleaning but instead commented hints as I suspect this is homework. However, you get a feeling with my code how to solve the last past (which is not part of your question when this was posted). Prints are there to show what happens. Enjoy.

```py
# an extra data entry included to show duplicate issue you might encounter with your dataset.
list_1 = [['53', 'James'], ['65', 'James'], ['26', 'Bob'], ['65', 'John']] 
list_temp = []

values_seen = []
values_dup  = []    # add here your score duplicates (see comment below)

ids = 0  # positional ID tag for each data-entry if score is similar to one in list (gets 
         # filtered out if you make it a dict but remains in lists). This allows you to id 
         # duplicates in names and scores but are in fact two different persons.

for item in list_1:   # add unique position identifier (in case there are similar names in the list with different score.)
    ids +=1
    list_temp.append((item[0], ids))
    values_seen.append(item[0])        # hook to check later for duplicate scores.

l = list(reversed(sorted(list_temp)))  # sorted score from highest to lowest

print (list_temp)
print (l)

list_final = []

# link name to its score.
for item in l:
    print (item[1])
    list_final.append([item[0], list_1[item[1]-1][1]])  

print (list_final, '\n', values_seen)

print ("...and the winner is : %s" % list_final[0]) # procedure does not take into account shared winners.
```

Another alternative is:

```py
with open ("write.csv", "r") as file:
    sortlist=[]
    reader=csv.reader(file)
    for i in reader:
        sortlist.append(i)

sortlist.sort(reverse=True)

...snippet...
```

Update:

There is between `with open ("write.csv", "r") as file:` and `for i in range(len(sortlist)):` a possibility to perform the sorting like I suggested above.

```
with open ("write.csv", "r") as file:
    sortlist=[]
    reader=csv.reader(file)
    for i in reader:
        sortlist.append(i)

# a variation of l = list(reversed(sorted(list_temp))) using "sortlist"  goes here
# sorted score from highest to lowest. Keep in mind duplicate scores.

for i in range(len(sortlist)):   #it does not order correctly
    if i != 0:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: the 'list_1' does not have the names and numbers its just list_1=username and score

Comment: it should be something like list_1=[score, username]    but am not sure

Comment: All i want is a line or a couple to add to my original code so it orders from highest to lowest alongside the 'username'

Comment: I did get that with `l = list(reversed(sorted(list_temp)))  ` which is exactly sorting the list and then reverse it to get the highest score first and lowest last (kinda no-brainer). As you wrote `with open ("write.csv", "r") as file:` I don't have the dataset with unsorted scores and names. I guess these are either in `score=points, username=winner` or in the write.csv file already somehow.... this is totally unclear to me and was the reason why I was asking for the dataset. Its now up to you to get that sorting inside your code where you want it. I've got this working script for you to use.

Comment: no, points is just a number and winner is just an input, this code is not in full its just a piece but that doesnt matter. And yes there is a dataset in write.csv.

Comment: This is what it shows in python['score', 'name']
['83', 'kug']
['57', 'kyhiv']
['33', 'kug']
['64', 'dxhr'] and in excel-score name
83 kug
57 kyhiv
33 kug
64 dxhr

Comment: Good... so if that dataset you just mentioned is in a list I would clip off [score, name] and follow my update and implement the code. Then you should be good to go. As mentioned before... be aware of the duplets (i.e. [83, kug][33, kug] are two subsets from the dataset having same name but could be different persons). For those duplets I showed how to use IDs for each subset in the dataset. GL.

Comment: could you just send the code so i can ctrl+c please

Comment: import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv("write.csv")
data.sort(["name", "score"], axis=0,
                 ascending=True, inplace=True)